# Specifying gpar settings for grid arrows in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm developing a plot of proportionally sized arrows, and have a workflow for size, direction and arrow-head size, but there are a couple of issues with the arrowheads: 1. they have rounded line-join and 2. they don't close (see bottom right corner) even when `type='closed'`.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
d = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 0, size = 1:10)

ggplot(d, aes(x, y, size = size)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = x, yend = y + size), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(d$size, "mm"), type='closed')) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 4))
```

[image]

Arrows are based on [grid graphics](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grid/html/arrow.html), but I cannot figure out how to specify the setting.  `get.gpar()` yields:

```
$lineend
[1] "round"

$linejoin
[1] "round"
```

but `gpar(linejoin = 'mitre', lineend = 'butt')` does not change this.  Is there any way to change these settings?  Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**

Plot image including grid.segments arrow added:

[image]

Comment: I don't get the same output, what graphics device etc. are you using?

Comment: do you see the same problem with raw grid, e.g. `grid.segments(x0=0.2, y0=0.2, x1=0.6, y1=0.6, arrow=arrow(type="closed"), gp=gpar(lwd=10, linejoin="mitre", fill="black"))`

Comment: Ah, it seems problem 2 (polygon closure) was just R gui's graphics device. But the rounding problem is still an issue (see new plot image above). This is result of png and pdf outputs (ggsave and base).

Comment: `geom_segment` doesn't seem to use linejoin and linemitre, you would have better luck with `geom_path`. You could post a feature request on github.

Comment: Thanks for the tips baptiste. Have submitted a feature request

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution (credit to @baptiste for the pointer).  If you use the [geom_segment source code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-segment.r) in github and make the following alterations you will end up with lovely pointy arrowheads:

1 `require(proto)`

2 add `ggplot:::` in first line of GeomSegment (currently line 51) as follows:

`GeomSegment <- proto(ggplot:::Geom, {`

3 add argument `linejoin = 'mitre'` to `gpar` in `segmentsGrob` (line 23):

`lwd=size * .pt, lty=linetype, lineend = lineend, linejoin = 'mitre'),`

Run both functions and you'll end up with:

[image]