# stacked bar chart with some negative values and ordered categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to construct a stacked bar plot (or arrow plot), preferably using `ggplot2`, with the example data `d` below, for each `id`.

The peculiarity is that I would like for the stack to follow the columns order `v0` first, `z1` second, and `z2` third (data is in wide format). Notice however that `z2` has some negative values. So it should somehow be represented by an arrow or something, from the top of the stack going down (or up, depending on the value of `z3`).

Is there a way to do this?

```
d <- data.frame(
  id=c('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF'),
  v0 =c( 50  , 60  , 40  , 50  , 70  ,40),
  z1 =c( 20  , 15  , 5   , 40  , 5  , 40),  
  z2 =c(-10  , 5   , 10  ,-20  , 15 ,-15)  
)

#normaly people transform the data to long format:
d %>% gather(ef_type, value,v0:d2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(...) + geom_bar(...)
```

OBS: Notice that this is different from the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734368/ggplot2-and-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-negative-values), in which the order of the columns does not matter, and the negative values are represented in the negative part of the y-axis.

EDIT1: based on @fanli answer bellow I tried the following code:

```
d %>% select(id,v0,z1) %>% gather(ef_type, value,v0:z1) -> df
d %>% mutate(z2_start=v0+z1,z2_end=v0+z1+z2) %>% select(id,z2_start,z2_end) -> df2

ggplot(df, aes(x=id,y=value,fill=ef_type))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  + geom_segment(data=df2, aes(x=id, xend=id, y=z2_start, yend=z2_end), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")))

#which results in the error:
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df <- melt(d)
df$absvalue <- abs(df$value)
df <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, pos = 
  ifelse(value<0, cumsum(absvalue)-(0.4 * absvalue), 
  cumsum(absvalue)-(0.6 * absvalue)))
df <- ddply(df, .(id), transform, pos2 = 
  ifelse(value>0, cumsum(absvalue)-(0.4 * absvalue), 
  cumsum(absvalue)-(0.6 * absvalue)))
ggplot(df, aes(x=id,y=absvalue,group=variable,fill=variable)) 
  + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") 
  + geom_segment(aes(x=id, xend=id, y=pos, yend=pos2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")))
```

[image]

You can play with the position/number/size of the arrows, but `geom_segment` seems like one possibility for what you'd like.

Edit: Based on clarification of desired output:

df <- melt(d)

```
ggplot(subset(df, variable!="z2"), aes(x=id,y=value,group=variable,fill=variable)) 
+ geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + geom_segment(data=d, 
  aes(x=id, xend=id, y=v0+z1, yend=v0+z1+z2), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")), inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]

Edit 2: Use `scale_fill_manual` and `scale_color_manual` to customize your legend keys:

```
d <- data.frame(
  id=c('AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF'),
  v0 =c( 50  , 60  , 40  , 50  , 70  ,40),
  z1 =c( 20  , 15  , 5   , 40  , 5  , 40),  
  z2 =c(-10  , 5   , 10  ,-20  , 15 ,-15)  
)
d$cc <- "effect B"
df <- melt(d)
ggplot(subset(df, variable!="z2"), aes(x=id,y=value,group=variable,fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") + geom_segment(data=d, aes(x=id, xend=id, y=v0+z1, yend=v0+z1+z2, color=cc), arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.02, "npc")), inherit.aes=F) + scale_color_manual(values="black") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("skyblue", "red"), labels=c("base level", "effect A"))
```

Comment: cool. It is more or less what I want. Cathegory z2 should not be displayed as a bar, only as an arrow, starting at "v0+z1" and ending at "v0+z1-z2"

Comment: This is great! The only problem remaining with this chart is that it would be nice to atribute some value to the legend. Lets say the labels are v0: "base level" ; z1: "effect A"; z2 (arrow) "effect B". Can this ne included in the legend somehow?

Comment: are you using reshape2::melt ? I tried replicating your code in my pc but I'm getting an error: Error in +geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: tks. I managed to make it work. Another possibility is to have both, z1 and z2 represented by arrows, as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468437/look-of-arrows-in-ggplot2-geom-segment (although as you see in the question thick arrows give rendering problems)