# How to add multiple arrows to a path according to line direction using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, path, line, direction

I have a data frame that I want to plot a path from. The data frame also indicates the direction the arrows should have. I have been using the `ggplot2` package and the `geom_path()` function for this, however, I want to add arrows that indicate the direction of the path. I used the `arrow()` function but I don't know how to make the arrows the way I would like (example below).

```
library(ggplot2)

X <- c(0.596, 0.641, 0.695, 0.741, 0.788, 0.837,
       0.887, 0.937, 0.993, 0.984, 0.934, 0.886,
       0.838, 0.778, 0.738, 0.681, 0.642, 0.593)

Y <- c(23.630, 24.085, 24.643, 25.067, 25.491, 25.899,
       26.305, 26.670, 27.049, 27.025, 26.836, 26.636,
       26.429, 26.152, 25.965, 25.664, 25.442, 24.510)

Direction <- c(rep('up', 9), rep('down', 9))

DF <- data.frame(X, Y, Direction)

ggplot(data = DF,
       aes(x = X,
           y = Y)) +
  geom_path(arrow = arrow(ends = "both"))
```

ggplot2 result

[image]

Desired result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. It assigns up arrow and down arrow based on the values in `Direction`. It does not follow the path orientation though.

```
DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, shape = factor(Direction))) + # converting to factor
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(24, 25)) + # 24 means up arrow and 25 down arrow
  geom_point(size = 2, fill = "black") +
  geom_line() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: @tjebo Edited my answer. I tried to make it clear what it does and what it does not.

Comment: Though it does, what user requires, yet use of geom_line instead of geom_path can lead to undesirable results most of the time.

Answer (score 7):

I'd split your path in segments and use geom_segment. Although the direction will be given by starting and end point in geom_segment, you will still need a grouping variable for your two paths, in order to avoid an ugly arrow between the two paths. Instead, you will get a barely noticeable gap. However, if you wish not to have this gap, omit the grouping step (`group_by`).

You can change the look of the arrows following [this popular thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008863/how-to-draw-a-nice-arrow-in-ggplot2).

Also maybe you want to have a look at the [metR package](https://eliocamp.github.io/metR/reference/index.html), there is a geom that creates arrows based on vectors

```
library(tidyverse)

X <- c(0.596, 0.641, 0.695, 0.741, 0.788, 0.837, 0.887, 0.937, 0.993, 0.984, 0.934, 0.886, 0.838, 0.778, 0.738, 0.681, 0.642, 0.593)
Y <- c(23.630, 24.085, 24.643, 25.067, 25.491, 25.899, 26.305, 26.670, 27.049, 27.025, 26.836, 26.636, 26.429, 26.152, 25.965, 25.664, 25.442, 24.510)
Direction <- c(rep('up', 9), rep('down', 9))

DF <- data.frame(X, Y, Direction)

DF %>%
group_by(Direction) %>%
mutate(xend = lead(X), yend = lead(Y)) %>%
ggplot( aes(x = X, y = Y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend), arrow = arrow())
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Instead of calculating `Direction`, you could place the arrows at the segment midpoints; this would alleviate the messy intersection where the line changes direction. For example: `DF %>% mutate(midx=c(X[-length(X)] + diff(X)/2, NA), midy=c(Y[-length(Y)] + diff(Y)/2, NA)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_segment(aes(x=midx, y=midy, xend=lead(midx), yend=lead(midy)), arrow=arrow())`